# How do I pause and unpause gameobjects on is own in the scene without pressing keys in unity3d

Tags: unity, unityscript, gameobject, pausing

I can't get my gameobject to pause or unpause in the scene in Unity3d. 
I need the game to pause for a couple of seconds maybe longer than unpause
 by itself. Here is my script :

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class hu : MonoBehaviour {
GameObject[] pauseObjects;
public bool isPaused;
 void Start () {

 pauseObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");

 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Pause () {
 
  {
   if(Time.timeScale == 1)
   {
    Time.timeScale = 7f;
    
   } else if (Time.timeScale == 8f){
   
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    
   }
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Time.timeScale affects your whole scene. It's not a per-gameObject value.

Comment: Also, you're checking for `timeScale == 8` but set it to 7. Also, none of those values are paused. Also also you renamed your function to `Pause` bit didn't remove the comment about the function being `Update`

Answer (score 2):

In Unity 5.4 you can use the built-in WaitForSecondsRealtime in your coroutine to safely modify timescale and avoid problem with WaitForSeconds when having timeScale == 0 as @DMGregory mentioned

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html

So it would be something like :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WaitForSecondsExample : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public void PauseAndAutoUnpause(float pauseTime) 
    {
        StartCoroutine(PauseAndAutoUnpauseCoroutine(pauseTime));
    }

    IEnumerator PauseAndAutoUnpauseCoroutine(float pauseTime) 
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;  // set timeScale to 0 will make your game paused
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(pauseTime);
        Time.timeScale = 1f; // we unpause the game by setting timeScale to its normal value, 1 
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use Coroutines.

```
void Pause(){
  StartCoroutine(waitToUnpause);
}

IENumerator waitToUnpause(){
  //do the thing to pause game
  Time.timeScale = 7f;//or some other method
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);///or any duration you want
  Time.timeScale = 1f;//or some other method
}
```

Comment: Just beware that if you try to pause the game by setting `Time.timeScale` to **zero**, then `WaitForSeconds()` will never resume the coroutine, since it counts seconds in *game time*, not realtime. Instead you may need to use a `while` loop with `yield return null` to wait a frame each iteration, then check `Time.realtimeSinceStartup` to determine when to break out & resume.

Comment: Also, how would that pause the game? Setting the `Time.timeScale` to `7f` will make the game run seven times faster not pause it.

Comment: I don't know. i have never messed with time scale. as i have commented in the code, tthe person should use their own way and i do not recommend messing with timescale myself